# Powershell: convert ForEach loop results into an HTML table

Tags: html, powershell, loops, converters

I wrote a code for Azure subscription cost calculation based on two Tags (In this case Application tag and Owner tag), that are used in our environment.

```
$ApplicationTags = ((Get-AzResource).Tags).Application | select -Unique
$ApplicationTagLoop = @(Foreach ($ApplicationTag in $ApplicationTags) {
    $ConsumptionUsageDetail = (Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate (Get-Date).addmonths(-1) -EndDate 
    (Get-Date)) | Where-Object {$_.Tags -ne $null} | Where-Object {$_.Tags['Application'] -eq 
    $ApplicationTag}
    $SumForApplicationTag = 0
    $TotalCostPerApplicationTag = $ConsumptionUsageDetail.PretaxCost
    $TotalCostPerApplicationTag | ForEach {$SumForApplicationTag += $_}
    Write-Host "Application tag is"$ApplicationTag". Sum for the tag is:" $([int]$SumForApplicationTag) "Eur" 
        $OwnerTags = ((Get-AzResource -TagValue $ApplicationTag).Tags).Owner | select -Unique
        ForEach ($OwnerTag in $OwnerTags) {
        $ConsumptionUsageDetail = (Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate (Get-Date).addmonths(-1) - 
        EndDate (Get-Date)) | Where-Object {$_.Tags -ne $null} | Where-Object {$_.Tags['Application'] -eq 
        $ApplicationTag} | Where-Object {$_.Tags['Owner'] -eq $OwnerTag}
        $SumForOwner = 0
        $TotalCostPerOwnerTag = $ConsumptionUsageDetail.PretaxCost
        $TotalCostPerOwnerTag | Foreach {$sumforowner += $_}
        ConvertTo-HTML -Body "Application tag: $ApplicationTag 'Owner: $OwnerTag Cost: 
        $([int]$SumForOwner) Eu." -Title "Cost of subscriptions" | Out-File c:\example.html
        Write-Host Owner is - $OwnerTag" Sum for the owner is:" $([int]$SumForOwner) "Eur"
    }
})
```

Output of this PS code is:

```
Application tag is Testing. Sum for the tag is: 25 Eur
Owner is - john.johnson@contoso.com Sum for the owner is: 15 Eur
Owner is - tom.thompson@contoso.com Sum for the owner is: 10 Eur
Application tag is Testing 2. Sum for the tag is: 100 Eur
Owner is - jim.jameson@contoso.com Sum for the owner is: 40 Eur
Owner is - eve.evens@contoso.com Sum for the owner is: 40 Eur
Owner is - charles.mcgill@contoso.com Sum for the owner is: 20Eur
```

...and so on...

Now I need to stream this output to an HTML table somehow, I tried doing that with ConvertTo-HTML command but it keeps rewriting itself with the last output and does not populate the table in any way.
I also tried to make ForEach loops into arrays like so:
`$ApplicationTagLoop = @(foreach ($i in $ApplicationTag)`
And using that with Convert-To-HTML, but doing it this way $ApplicationTagLoop does not provide any results at all, so nothing is converted to HTML.

How could I rewrite the ConvertTo-HTML part so that every output of the loop would be saved into a new line of the HTML file?

Desired output format should be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z13SM.png

Comment: What should the resulting table look like?

Comment: I've modified the original question, to better understand, how the final output should look like. Is it possible to modify $html variable (as seen in Zilog80 reply) for the output to produce the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewing the code, i guess the expected oputput.

Use object collection build to get proper HTML :

```
$ApplicationTags = ((Get-AzResource).Tags).Application | select -Unique
$html = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
Foreach ($ApplicationTag in $ApplicationTags) {
    $ConsumptionUsageDetail = (Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate (Get-Date).addmonths(-1) -EndDate 
    (Get-Date)) | Where-Object {$_.Tags -ne $null} | Where-Object {$_.Tags['Application'] -eq 
    $ApplicationTag}
    $SumForApplicationTag = 0
    $TotalCostPerApplicationTag = $ConsumptionUsageDetail.PretaxCost
    $TotalCostPerApplicationTag | ForEach {$SumForApplicationTag += $_}
    Write-Host "Application tag is"$ApplicationTag". Sum for the tag is:" $([int]$SumForApplicationTag) "Eur" 
        $OwnerTags = ((Get-AzResource -TagValue $ApplicationTag).Tags).Owner | select -Unique
        ForEach ($OwnerTag in $OwnerTags) {
           $ConsumptionUsageDetail = (Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate (Get-Date).addmonths(-1) - 
           EndDate (Get-Date)) | Where-Object {$_.Tags -ne $null} | Where-Object {$_.Tags['Application'] -eq 
             $ApplicationTag} | Where-Object {$_.Tags['Owner'] -eq $OwnerTag}
           $SumForOwner = 0
           $TotalCostPerOwnerTag = $ConsumptionUsageDetail.PretaxCost
           $TotalCostPerOwnerTag | Foreach {$sumforowner += $_}
           #ConvertTo-HTML -Body "Application tag: $ApplicationTag 'Owner: $OwnerTag Cost:         
               #$([int]$SumForOwner) Eu." -Title "Cost of subscriptions" | Out-File c:\example.html
           $html.Add((Select-Object @{n='Application tag';e={$ApplicationTag}},@{n='Owner';e={$OwnerTag}},@{n='Cost';e={[string]$([int]$SumForOwner)+" Eu."}} -InputObject ''))
           Write-Host Owner is - $OwnerTag" Sum for the owner is:" $([int]$SumForOwner) "Eur"
    }
}; $html |  ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Title "Cost of subscriptions"  | Out-File c:\example.html
```

Which should render the following HTML :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Cost of subscriptions</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Application tag</th><th>Owner</th><th>Cost</th></tr>
<tr><td>Testing</td><td>john.johnson@contoso.com</td><td>15 Eu</td></tr>
<tr><td>Testing</td><td>tom.thompson@contoso.com</td><td>10 Eu</td></tr>
<tr><td>Testing 2</td><td>jim.jameson@contoso.com</td><td>40 Eu</td></tr>
<tr><td>Testing 2</td><td>eve.evens@contoso.com</td><td>40 Eu</td></tr>
<tr><td>Testing 2</td><td>charles.mcgill@contoso.com</td><td>20 Eu</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

[image]

Second edit as OP required a new formatted output, we're using a hash to break by application tag and format the output accordingly.

```
$ApplicationTags = ((Get-AzResource).Tags).Application | select -Unique
$html = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$hash = @{}
Foreach ($ApplicationTag in $ApplicationTags) {
    $ConsumptionUsageDetail = (Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate (Get-Date).addmonths(-1) -EndDate 
    (Get-Date)) | Where-Object {$_.Tags -ne $null} | Where-Object {$_.Tags['Application'] -eq 
    $ApplicationTag}
    $SumForApplicationTag = 0
    $TotalCostPerApplicationTag = $ConsumptionUsageDetail.PretaxCost
    $TotalCostPerApplicationTag | ForEach {$SumForApplicationTag += $_}
    Write-Host "Application tag is"$ApplicationTag". Sum for the tag is:" $([int]$SumForApplicationTag) "Eur" 
        $OwnerTags = ((Get-AzResource -TagValue $ApplicationTag).Tags).Owner | select -Unique
        ForEach ($OwnerTag in $OwnerTags) {
           $ConsumptionUsageDetail = (Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate (Get-Date).addmonths(-1) - 
           EndDate (Get-Date)) | Where-Object {$_.Tags -ne $null} | Where-Object {$_.Tags['Application'] -eq 
             $ApplicationTag} | Where-Object {$_.Tags['Owner'] -eq $OwnerTag}
           $SumForOwner = 0
           $TotalCostPerOwnerTag = $ConsumptionUsageDetail.PretaxCost
           $TotalCostPerOwnerTag | Foreach {$sumforowner += $_}
           # We use the hash to check for break by ApplicationTag
           if (!$hash[ApplicationTag]) { 
               $hash[$ApplicationTag]=$True
               $html.Add((Select-Object @{n="Application tag";e={$ApplicationTag}},@{n="Owner";e={""}},@{n="Cost";e={[string]$([int]$SumForApplicationTag)+" Eu."}} -InputObject ''))
           }
           # Adding the owners
           $html.Add((Select-Object @{n="Application tag";e={""}},@{n='Owner';e={$OwnerTag}},@{n='Cost';e={[string]$([int]$SumForOwner)+" Eu."}} -InputObject ''))
           Write-Host Owner is - $OwnerTag" Sum for the owner is:" $([int]$SumForOwner) "Eur"
    }
}; $html |  ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Title "Cost of subscriptions"  | Out-File c:\example.html
```

Which should render the following HTML :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Cost of subscriptions</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>ApplicationTag</th><th>Owner</th><th>Cost</th></tr>
<tr><td>Testing</td><td></td><td>25 Eu</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>john.johnson@contoso.com</td><td>15 Eu</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>tom.thompson@contoso.com</td><td>10 Eu</td></tr>
<tr><td>Testing 2</td><td></td><td>100 Eu</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>jim.jameson@contoso.com</td><td>40 Eu</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>eve.evens@contoso.com</td><td>40 Eu</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>charles.mcgill@contoso.com</td><td>20 Eu</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Wich should render as :

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect! 
But I'd like to change the output to be a bit more informative. In this case, we need to see the total cost of the Application tag, before listing Owner cost. I've modified the original question, to better understand, how the final output should look like. Is it possible to modify $html variable for the output to produce the desired result?

Comment: @Darzas, done using a hash. This could have be done simply with a simple string variable, but i'm sure using a hash will give you ideas on what you can do in powershell with structured collections.

Comment: This is perfect!! Thank you for the help!